# Reverse association in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, redmine

Right now I'm programming a plugin for the project managment app Redmine.
And since I'm new to Rails, I have a question about a query.

Redmine provides me with an Issue model. In my plugin I'm defining an additional IssueRates model, which has the following associations:

```
class IssueRates < ActiveRecord::Base
unloadable

belongs_to :issue,
...
```

However, I don't want to change the standard Issue model to have a `has_one association`, to keep the redmine code as clean as possible.

But now I need a query like this:

```
project_issues=Issue.where(:project_id => some_id)
project_issues.each do |i|
    puts i.IssueRates.amount
end
```

Which obviously doesn't work, because of the missing association. Is there a way to reverse this association? Because then, I could even use eager loading with `.includes(:IssueRates)`.

If this is not possible, I could still get the IssueRates in a separate query...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you could do:

```
IssueRates.find_by_issue_id(i.id).amount
```

It seems like more work than just adding `has_one` to your Issue model.

Comment: yeah, i knew how to get the IssueRates from the Issues, but i was curious if it's possible to use an association the other way round in Rails. I'm pretty sure that it is possible in django's ORM.